# Reducing an expression with exponents: $(3x-4)^{1/2}+(2x+2)(3x-4)^{-1/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing an exercise which requires the student to simplify $(3x-4)^{1/2}+(2x+2)(3x-4)^{-1/2}$. The answer given in the back of the book is $\frac{(5x-2)}{(3x-4)^{1/2}}$. The only way I can see how they got this answer is by removing the fractional exponent from the numerator and adding $(3x-4)$ to $(2x+2)$. When I go through the process of simplifying I get $\frac{(3x-4)^{3/2}+2x+2}{(3x-4)^{1/2}}$. Is the answer wrong? Am I on the wrong track?

Thanks.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1$ . Not $\frac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that $a^{-k} = \frac{1}{a^k}$. We can now reduce the expression
\begin{align}
(3x - 4)^\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2x + 2}{(3x - 4)^\frac{1}{2}}
&= \frac{(3x - 4)^\frac{1}{2}(3x - 4)^\frac{1}{2}}{(3x - 4)^\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{2x + 2}{(3x - 4)^\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \frac{(3x - 4)^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}} + 2x + 2} {(3x - 4)^\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \frac{3x - 4 + 2x + 2}{(3x - 4)^\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \frac{5x - 2}{(3x - 4)^\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Makes perfect sense. I forgot to add the exponents together when multiplying the first term by 1.